# Retaining pandas dataframe rows which have maximum number of item occurrences in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','joe','bill','richard','sam'],
                  'cluster':['1','2','3','1','2']})
```

`df['cluster'].value_counts()` will give the number of occurrences of items based on the column `cluster`.

Is it possible to retain only the rows which have the maximum number of occurrences in the column `cluster`?

The expected output is

[image]

The cluster 1 and 2 have the same number of occurrences, so all the rows for cluster 1 and 2 need to be retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the max count of `cluster` value through `df['cluster'].value_counts()` then use `isin` to filter `cluster` column

```py
c = df['cluster'].value_counts()

out = df[df['cluster'].isin(c[c.eq(c.max())].index)]
```

```
print(out)

      name cluster
0     john       1
1      joe       2
3  richard       1
4      sam       2
```

Answer (score 3):

Group by 'cluster' and use `transform('count')` to get a Series of occurrences by clusters with the appropriate shape. Then use it to mask only the rows corresponding to the max occurrences.

```
cluster_counts = df.groupby('cluster')['name'].transform('count')
res = df[cluster_counts == cluster_counts.max()]
```

Output:

```
>>> res

      name cluster
0     john       1
1      joe       2
3  richard       1
4      sam       2
```

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','joe','bill','richard','sam'],
                   'cluster':['1','2','3','1','2']})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```py
# find the most common clusters then filter those clusters
df[df.cluster.isin(df.cluster.mode())]
```

[image]